# Jquery to make buttons that enlarge and shrink text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I've gone through several similar questions on here, but as I am relatively new to JavaScript and completely new to JQuery, I dont really know what im doing :D

So my assignment is to make two divs with text in them:

```
<div id = "changeable" class = "normal">
    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
</div>
<div id = "staysSame">
    <p>Bloo bloo bloo bloo bloo bloo bloo bloo bloo</p>
</div>
```

Then I'm supposed to make two buttons with event handlers that change the font size using JQuery/JavaScript/CSS

```
<input type = "button" onclick = "button1Click()" id = "button1" value = "Enlarge"></input>
<input type = "button" onclick = "button2Click()" id = "button2" value = "Shrink"></input>
```

I'm supposed to make a CSS page for each font size (this is exactly how I need it, other than the exact font sizes)

```
.large{
    font-size: 20pt;
}
.normal{
    font-size: 14pt;
}
.small{
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

And since I am new to JQuery, I have no idea how to use it for the most part. So right now I just have some JavaScript that doesn't work. Which is not surprising because I don't know much JS either wooooo

```
var large = GetElementByClassName("large");
var normal = GetElementByClassName("normal");
var small = GetElementByClassName("small");

function button1Click(){
    normal.style.fontsize = large.style.fontsize;
}
function button2Click(){
    normal.style,.fontsize = small.style.fontsize;
}
```

Thanks all help is appreciated!

Comment: what is GetElementByClassName

Comment: @Alexander Please do not change the OP's original code when editing a post, unless you are formatting it

Answer (score 1):

There re several problems in your code.

1. The function to call is `document.getElementsByClassName()`, not `GetElementsByClassName`.
2. It returns a collection, not a single element. To change all the elements in the collection, you need to write a loop.
3. You have an extra comma in `normal.style,.fontsize`.

Since you're using jQuery, you can simplify it, since it automatically iterates for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button1").click(function() {
        var change = $("#changeable");
        if (change.hasClass("small")) {
            change.toggleClass("small normal");
        } else if (change.hasClass("normal")) {
            change.toggleClass("normal large");
        }
    });
    $("#button2").click(function() {
        var change = $("#changeable");
        if (change.hasClass("large")) {
            change.toggleClass("large normal");
        } else if (change.hasClass("normal")) {
            change.toggleClass("normal small");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: maybe Im just stupid, your code seems like i can just plug it in (like copy and paste it basically) and it should work fine but when I try it out, it doesn't work and I cant figure out why. I've looked it over and it seems to make sense to me that all the names and ID's and class names are correct but for whatever reason its not working im sorry

Comment: Did you put it in the `$(document).ready()` function? That's where most jQuery code should go, so it runs after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: I did not do that and also dont know what you mean haha im sorry. this is also my first time using stack exchange.
anyways, did you mean $(document).ready($("#button1").click(function(){code}) $("#button1").click(function(){code})   ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I also had some syntax errors before, they're fixed now.

Comment: What tutorial are you reading to learn jQuery? I can't believe it doesn't show how to use `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: im actually taking a class at Simmons and the teacher is just horrible :) like. Any other teacher in the entire department, and i wouldnt be so insecure about my javascript skills. Ill try it out again though thank you!

Comment: Okay so the "blah blah blah" and "bloo bloo bloo" parts are not exactly what i have that i want the page to print out, i have other things written i just thought it would be easier on the question to replace those parts with something mindless. Anyways, I have two <p>'s in my first div and one in my second div, and the very first <p> is larger than the rest of the text on the page, but that happens before i hit any buttons.

Comment: oh my god okay so im stupid and forgot that my teacher told me to make my other text have the ID "staysSame" so im guessing its just supposed to be like that. So the problem isnt which text is enlarged, its when the text is enlarged. aka its large when the page loads.

Comment: I didn't notice before that `changeable` was an ID, not a class. I've updated the answer to access it properly. But it seems strange that you would have just one DIV that was changeable, not lots of DIVs on the page.

Answer (score 1):

1) There is no JS method called "GetElementByClassName" - there's `getElementsByClassName()` or `getElementById()`. Pay attention to the method names - they're case sensitive & are easy to confuse.

Use "Id" when you want to return a single unique element (because IDs should be unique on the page, right?), and "elements (plural)" ByClassName to return every element that has that particular class - could be 1000 things on a page.

2) You haven't applied the "large" or "small" CSS classes to your divs in the HTML. JS/jQuery looks at the HTML "Document Object Model" and what it contains. It doesn't know or care about the CSS file, which seems to be how you're approaching it. Trying to get elements w/those class names won't return anything you can use until you first apply the class to elements in the document.

You can either hard-code this in the HTML, as you've done by adding `class="normal"` to the 1st div ... Or you can add/remove/toggle the classes dynamically [with jQuery:](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
   //play w/toggleClass() as well as chaining multiple jQuery methods
   //like .addClass() and .removeClass() to get the effect you want
   //read the jQuery documentation for examples & details.    

    $("#changeable").toggleClass(normal small); 

});
```

This approach is ideal for keeping your JS, CSS, and HTML separate. Alternatives like directly accessing `.style` or using the `.css()` method tend to mix things up, as you already noticed.

3) Using inline JS handlers like "onclick()" is easy, but rather outdated practice because it's a pain to maintain (imagine an HTML page w/100 buttons on it, and then you need to change all of them...). Preferred approach is to use an event listener.

With jQuery you can use:

`$(".yourClassName").on('click', function() {//dostuff here});`

Or the shortcut method `.click(someFunction())` which does the same thing.

4) Do you know how to use the console or set a breakpoint in an inspector like Firebug to inspect/debug your code for errors? Look into that so you can figure out where your code is breaking, and from there determine why.

5) If you don't understand JS or jQuery, read the documentation. Mozilla Developer Network is a good JS resource. jQuery docs are here: http://api.jquery.com/ . If those don't make sense (they won't at first), there are tons of tutorials online that can help explain it - Lynda.com, Treehouse, tuts+, etc. Copy/pasting after asking others to do your homework for you won't teach you much of anything. If this is something you really want to learn, try to understand how things work & why - not just what to do. Good luck!

Comment: `JS/jQuery looks at the HTML "Document Object Model" and what it contains. It doesn't know or care about the CSS file` not true. CSS files are parsed and the properties are added to DOM Nodes. The browser then uses the DOM tree to render the page.

Comment: @papirtiger: At which point it's part of "the DOM & what it contains" - not an external file ... From OP's code it seemed like he expected his JS to be able to interact directly with the CSS file, which is not what happens. That's what I wanted to clarify. He's not adding the CSS properties to any elements on the page, so he has nothing to target.

Comment: True, it was mostly just the wording that threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it using jQuery, you can add a .click(function(e){}) listener and use that to change the size of the text inside a certain element. such as

```
<div id='textDiv'> <p> Just some text </p> </div>
<button id='textSmallerButton'>smaller text</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   $("#textSmallerButton").click(function(e) {
       $("#textDiv").css("font-size", "12px");
   });
</script>
```

(Bigger is mostly the same, just other size of font) 
Just remember to set the ID's right :)

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but it looks perfect to me, which is exciting as a person who doesn't know what he's talking about!!

Comment: Im kind of confused when translating your answer into my documents because im supposed to keep my CSS and JS seperate from my HTML, it it looks like your answer is how to do it all on one document. I know some little changes occur when you have everything seperate I just cant figure out how to translate that...

Comment: Just include the javascript in the head of your HTML, be wary though, you might need to add `$(document).ready(function(){ -Javascript- });` caller to make sure the button works.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class of your object;

```
function button1Click(){
    $(this).removeClass("normal small").addClass("large");
}
function button2Click(){
    $(this).removeClass("normal large").addClass("small");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First things first:**

Adding spaces around the `=` sign in HMTL is not common - while not technically wrong - it uses tons of space on each line and is pretty hard to read since its harder to see where each attributes begins:

```
<div class = "something" id = "other">
<div class="something" id="other">
```

Plus this is bound to annoy any future colleges immensely.

Since we are using jQuery its pretty easy to get rid of the nasty inline attribute handlers. 
We can leave them back in the 90´s where they belong.

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Enlarge"></input>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Shrink"></input>
```

Keeping our HTML and Javascript separate turns out to be a very good thing since it makes our HTML a lot less messy.

jQuery allows us to use [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) which are very succinct and awesome to select elements so that we can bind handlers to them. `#` denotes an id. `.` denotes a class.

```
$('#button1'); // jQuery Gimme an element with the ID of 'button1' if you please 
$('.icecream'); // all elements with the class 'icecream'
$('.icecream.vanilla'); // with the class 'icecream' and 'vanilla'
```

jQuery turns these CSS selector expressions into calls to the built in `document.querySelectorAll`, `document.getElementById` ... functions. The magic here is we don't really need care that old browsers may not include some parts of the infamous DOM api - jQuery will take care of it for us (well hopefully at least).

So lets go over line by line how we would add functionality to our shrink and enlarge buttons:

```
// Run this when the page is fully loaded and ready
$(function(){

    // We get the element with the Id changeable
    var $changeable = $("#changeable");

    // lets create an event handler for the enlarge button
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        // we check if changeable is small and save the value so 
        // we remember what state our text has even if we reset it
        var isSmall = $changeable.hasClass('small');
        // lets reset everything just to be sure
        $changeable.removeClass('small normal large');
        // This lets us "step" up to normal size if the text is small 
        // instead of going directly from small to large
        if (isSmall) {
            $changeable.addClass('normal');
        } else {
            $changeable.addClass('large');
        }
    });

    // Event handler for the shrink button - the same as enlarge but opposite 
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        var isLarge = $changeable.hasClass('large');
        $changeable.removeClass('small normal large');
        if (isLarge) {
            $changeable.addClass('normal');
        } else {
            $changeable.addClass('small');
        }
    });
});
```

You can try it out and see tests which prove it works as we intended in in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maxcal/d1rydapr/6/.

Comment: I dont understand theres no reason my my code should not be working right now, what youre saying is completely right (and extremely helpful in general to be honest, i learned way more with you in 10 seconds of reading than i have with this teacher and we're halfway through the semester) but i cant get my thing to run the way it runs on your jsfiddle link. I even tried literally copying and pasting the code you have in jsfiddle and it isnt doing what its supposed to do. I tried closing out of everything and opening it back up but you know. whatever. Thank you so much i appreciate everyones help

Answer (score -1):

You could use the "css" property.

For example:

```
$("#changeable").css({"font-size":"12px"});
```